# syntax error for an initialized list in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to translate a page of C# into VB as I complete the ASP MVC 3 music store tutorial. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

The page is a bunch of sample data that will get pulled into the DB.

The C# that i am trying to translate looks like this:

```
        new List<Album>  
        {
            new Album { Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Classical"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },

         //lots of albums here... just like examples above and below

            new Album { Title = "Ao Vivo [IMPORT]", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Latin"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Zeca Pagodinho"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
        }.ForEach(a => context.Albums.Add(a));
```

My converted VB code looks like this, but the compiler says that there is a syntax error on the first line...

```
New List(Of Album)() With { _             //Compiler says there is a syntax error here
            New Album() With { _
                 .Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", _
                 .Genre = genres.[Single](Function(g) g.Name = "Classical"), _
                 .Price = 8.99D, _
                 .Artist = artists.[Single](Function(a) a.Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), _
                 .AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" _
            }, _

       //lots of albums here 

            New Album() With { _
                .Title = "Ao Vivo [IMPORT]", _
                 .Genre = genres.[Single](Function(g) g.Name = "Latin"), _
                 .Price = 8.99D, _
                 .Artist = artists.[Single](Function(a) a.Name = "Zeca Pagodinho"), _
                 .AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" _
             } _
}.ForEach(Function(a) context.Albums.Add(a))
```

How can I fix the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need (at least) parentheses around the construct and, I think, also a `Call` (you needed that at least in previous VB versions, I don’t now if VB10 still requires it); furthermore, the `With` after the list constructor [should be a `From`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) (but it’s required after the other constructors):

```
Call (New List(Of Album) From { _
    …
}).ForEach(…)
```

Furthermore, `ForEach` requires a `Sub`, not a `Function`. (And, by the way, the line continuation underscores are redundant in VB10.)

But both in VB and C# this is just horribly messy code. Just assign the expression to an object in its initialiser, and invoke `ForEach` on *that*.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. The compiler is giving an error with your suggestion ("Expression is not a method"). Can you show me how to build a list of anonymous types so I can just call for each as you suggest?

Comment: *What* error does it give? Also, the types here are *not* anonymous (the type is `Album`).

Comment: @akh2103 See update. There also was a redundant `With` after the list constructor that should have been a `From`.

Comment: That got it working. The code is from Microsoft! I'm just trying to fill the DB to learn asp mvc 3! But yeah, it is really confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you an extra `With` and an extra set of curly brackets. I think your syntax should be like this:

```
 New List(Of SomeThing)(
     {
     New SomeThing With {.name = "foo"}, 
     New SomeThing With {.name = "bar"}
     }
 )
```

So your example should look like this:

```
    Dim a As New List(Of Album)({
          New Album() With {.Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I"},
          New Album() With {.Title = "Ao Vivo [IMPORT]"}})
```

But I agree with Konrad - this code is horrible!

Comment: Thanks Matt. Your suggestion got rid of the compiler error for the Dim a as new list of album. But now it is giving the error "End of Statement Expected" for the final line of code:    ).ForEach(Function(a) context.Albums.Add(a))